# Find $C\in\mathbb R$ such that $(2,3,5)$ be in $\text{Im}(F)$

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $$\color{red}{\underbrace{F:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3\;|}_{\text{Added by me}}}\; F(x,y,z)=(x+Cz,\;x+y+2z,\;x+Cy)$$ a linear transformation. Find $C\!\!\!\!\!\color{red}{\underbrace{\in\mathbb R}_{\text{Added by me}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!$ such that $(2,3,5)$ be in $\text{Im}(F)$.

---

I don't know hot to interpet the statement. I think I need to solve the equation $$F(x,y,z)=(2,3,5)\qquad\text{i.e.}\qquad(x+Cz,\;x+y+2z,\;x+Cy)=(2,3,5),$$ but this is a system equations of $3\times 4$. Is correct my reasoning? If so, how can it solve to find $C$?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you find a $C \in \mathbb{R}$ for which there exists (at least one) vector $(x,y,z)$ such that $F(x,y,z)=(2,3,5)$.  For example, $C=0$ does not work since then $F(x,y,z) = (x, x+y+2z,x)$ and so the first and third coordinates must match, meaning we cannot have $(2,3,5)$.

Comment: @Michael OK, so it's like saying "If $f(x)=2xC$ find $C$ such that $4$ be in $\text{Im}(f)$". So I did $2xC=4\Rightarrow C=\frac 2x\;\wedge\;x\neq 0$, no?

Comment: We do not care if it holds for _all_ $x$.  We just want a particular $x$ for which $f(x)=2xC=4$. So we could use $x=1$ then $f(1)=2C$, and to make that 4 we use $C=2$.  So your description of "and $x\neq 0$" is overly complicated.

Comment: @Michael It's like "$\forall x\;\exists C\mid\;\ldots$"? I think we need to find a generic solution, not just one who makes the statement true. The place from which I copied the statement was written as "Find $C$ *for which* $(2,3,5)$ be in $\text{Im}(F)$" (in plural).

Comment: No. Again, you do not care that it holds for _all_ $x$.  Another way to think about the problem is to find $C$ such that the columns of the $3 \times 3$ matrix that defines $F$ are linearly independent.  Recall that $(2,3,5) \in Im(F)$ means exactly that there exists a _particular_ $(x,y,z)$ such that $F(x,y,z) = (2,3,5)$. [There are many $C$ values that work, if you test a few you will easily find one.  Don't test $C=0$ since we already know that does not work.]

Comment: @Michael OK, I think there are infinity values of $C$ (but we are interested in only one who makes the statement true, right? A graphic representation would be these?: https://imgur.com/a/8hIQaJn

Comment: Yes, as long as the picture means that $(2,3,5)$ is just one point, amongst many, in the image of $F$. For example, clearly $(0,0,0)$ is also in the image of $F$.  [ Also, I would prefer the picture to show a particular point $(x,y,z)$ in the domain mapping to $(2,3,5)$ in the range via the function $F$. ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(x+Cz, x+y+2z, x+Cy)=(2,3,5)$$
$$\implies x+Cz=2;~~~ x+y+2z=3;~~~~ x+Cy=5$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&C\\1&1&2\\1&C&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\5\end{bmatrix}$$
applying row transformation, $R_2\leftarrow R_2-R_1$, $R_3\leftarrow R_3-R_1$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&C\\0&1&2-C\\0&C&-C\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}$$
$R_3\leftarrow R_3-C R_2$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&C\\0&1&2-C\\0&0&C^2-3C\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\3-C\end{bmatrix}$$
For unique solution $(x,y,z)$, we take $C$ different from $3$.
NOTE:- for $C=0$, rank of coefficient matrix is not equal to rank of augmented matrix. Hence, for $C=0$ solution does not exist.

Take $C=1$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$
$R_3\leftarrow \frac{-1}{2}R_3$ followed by $R_2\leftarrow R_2-R_3$, $R_1\leftarrow R_1-R_3$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$x=3;~~y=2;~~z=-1.$$

$$(x+Cz, x+y+2z, x+Cy)=(3+1(-1),3+2+2(-1),3+1(2))=(2,3,5)$$